# php PHPExcel split Excel cell coordinate

Tags: php, regex, split, phpexcel

currently, I used PHPExcel to import excel file,
there is a function `$cell->getCoordinate();`

I would like to ask any solution for split the cell coordinate `alphabet` and `integer`?

**e.g A1, A2,**

I need to know currently which row, and until which column.

I do some research about split, but not luck for it. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
$coord = 'AF13';
preg_match_all('~[A-Z]+|\d+~', $coord, $split);
print_r($split);
```

Will produce:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => AF
    [1] => 13
  )
)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I really lag of knowledge in regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
$coordinate = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('A1');
var_dump($coordinate);
```